# Cannot find "electron-fetch" in packaged electron

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm currently trying to package my electron(-forge) (Webpack, React, TS) app, which uses [electron-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-fetch) in the renderer process with:

```
const fetch = window
.require("electron").remote
.require("electron-fetch").default;
```

If I start with `yarn start` the application works fine.

But when running the packaged app (from `yarn package`), I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'electron-fetch'
 Require stack:
 - path_to_app/resources/app/.webpack/main/index.js
```

When electron-fetch is removed the packaged app runs fine.

Node: v14.17.4
Yarn: 1.22.11

Answer (score 0):

It might be Electron cannot read the **electron-fetch**  binary **in app.asar**. Make sure to exclude the **electron-fetch** module from app.asar in production or don't package your app as asar encrypted. Read this issue [Unable to access a file inside asar package](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/751)

Comment: I'm not using .asar archives

Comment: Don't use electron. remote module it is officially removed by electronV14.